# Проблема с отображением css слайдера в Safari

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Всем доброго времени суток. Верстаю css слайдер. В принципе все готово. Проверил в Chrome, FF , Opera,IE 11. Все ОК, но  в чертовом Safari отказывается нормально работать. Может кто подскажет - почему так происходит?

```
<div class="horizontal-click">
  <input type="radio" name="vkl" id="vkl1" checked="checked"/>
  <label for="vkl1">Заголовок 1</label>
  <div>Вкладка 1</div>

    <input type="radio" name="vkl" id="vkl2"/>
    <label for="vkl2">Заголовок 2</label>
    <div>Вкладка 2</div>

  <input type="radio" name="vkl" id="vkl3"/>
  <label for="vkl3">Заголовка 3</label>
  <div>Вкладка 3</div>

</div>
```

На [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/nhp1c0bo/).

Answer (score 1):

Если долго мучатся, то один из ответов на вопрос может быть таким:

```css
.horizontal-click [name="vkl"] {
  display: none;
}
.horizontal-click >:not(input):not(label) {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  border-top-style: none;
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
}
.horizontal-click > label {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  background: #606060;
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.horizontal-click >:checked + label ~ div {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 110px;
}
.horizontal-click >:not(:checked) + label + div {
  height: 0;
}
.horizontal-click >:checked + label {
  background: #454545;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-click">
  <input type="radio" name="vkl" id="vkl1" checked="checked" />
  <label for="vkl1">Заголовок 1</label>
  <div>Вкладка 1</div>

  <input type="radio" name="vkl" id="vkl2" />
  <label for="vkl2">Заголовок 2</label>
  <div>Вкладка 2</div>

  <input type="radio" name="vkl" id="vkl3" />
  <label for="vkl3">Заголовка 3</label>
  <div>Вкладка 3</div>

</div>
```